# Trying to add a If Statement inside a Timer in VB 2010

Tags: visual-studio, if-statement, timer, basic

I have looked but cant seem to find out why this won't work for me

I added this Code inside Timer1 in my form

```
dim Boolean1 as Boolean

if Boolean1 = true and WMP1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying then
WMP1.Ctlcontrols.pause()
Boolean1 = false
end if
if Boolean1 = false and WMP1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPaused then
WMP1.Ctlcontrols.play()
Boolean1 = true
end if
```

Comment: pleas give declaration of WMP1. IWMPControls act on the player, AxWindowsMediaPlayer is a read-only property. Besides, should your "end-if if" not be an "elseif", to bypass modifications made in the first part?

Comment: What is Boolean1 equal to in the first place?